# HTML scroll long text vertically

Tags: html, css

```
<pre id="${item.id}"> <div style="overflow:auto; width:750px; max-height:150px;">${item.template[item.prop2]}</div></pre>
```

I have large content inside the div, but it scrolls horizontally. I want the text to break after width of 750 px and start with next line with vertical scroll only.

Comment: Overflow-x should be hidden then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<pre>` tag doesn't wrap text by default! You should use the following solution:

```css
pre#test {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;
  white-space: -pre-wrap;
  white-space: -o-pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<pre id="test">
  <div style="width:750px;max-height:75px;overflow:auto;word-wrap: break-word;">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </div>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

The overflow:auto style would cause both x and y axis to scroll. You could use overflow-y:auto, instead. This will only allow scrolling on the y axis, or vertically.

```
<pre id="${item.id}"> <div style="overflow-y:auto; width:750px; max-height:150px;">${item.template[item.prop2]}</div></pre>
```